# Click on day name and select all days from the same day of week in Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

[image: my current calendar]

I have this calendar displayed in the image and i want to handle select by clicking on the day of week name. My idea is to click, lets say, monday, and the calendar selects all mondays in the current view. I looked everywhere in their documentation and could not find anything related.

Is it possible to make this?

Edit:

```
function enumerateDaysBetweenDates(startDate, endDate) {
    var now = startDate.clone(), dates = [];

    while (now.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
      dates.push(now.format('M/D/YYYY'));
      now.add(1, 'days');
    }
    return dates;
  };

  var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: ''
    },
    selectable: true,
    select: function (startDate, endDate) {
      var html = '<input class="form-control" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="' + startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' até ' + endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') +'" />';
      console.log(enumerateDaysBetweenDates(startDate, endDate.add(-1, 'days')));
      $('#selected-dateranges').append(html);
    } 
  });
```

I created a pen to make it simple to edit.
[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYPzvx)

Comment: And do what with all same days? Highlight the calendar day , events or ??

Comment: make an easter egg :D @charlietfl

Comment: I want to select it just like we can select with the selectable option. I have some logic that runs when the dates are selected. For example, i want to say the worker A works from 09:00 to 14:00 every wednesday, but saturday he works from 10:00 to 15:00. I think selecting by day of week will make this process easier for the user.

Comment: So my question is what is the higher level overview of what that logic does? You still haven't answered the very simple question I asked. It sounds like you want to filter events by day of week...but not sure

Comment: How not? i want to select these dates that are of the same weekday of the selected day name. In FullCalendar, when i select one date it automatically highlights these dates and triggers an event, what i will do with the selected date is not important here. So i do really think that i answered you.

Comment: Just got confusing with the irrelevant Worker A & B part

Comment: I posted a link to codepen. Maybe it helps somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic code is fairly simple.

The calendar day elements have classes `fc-mon`, `fc-tue` etc that are based on day names. They also have a base class of `fc-day`. So it is reasonably easy to get day text clicked on in header and transpose to a day name class and toggle a selected class on appropriate days

Try this

```
 $('#calendar').on('click', '.fc-day-header', function(e) {
     let day = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
     $('.fc-day').removeClass('selected')
                 .filter('.fc-' + day)
                 .addClass('selected')
 });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/SXnEqyBF2cOfhd0L4Rky?p=preview)**</kbd>